# Problem with Functions in Boolean Code for Python

Tags: python

```
def main():

    print(status)

def is_even(number):
    number = 100

    if (number % 2) == 0:
        status = True
    else:
        status = False
        
    return status

def is_negative(number):

    if (number < 0):
        status = True
    else:
        status = False

    return status

def is_too_big(number):

    if (number > 100):
        status = True
    else:
        status = False

    return status

main()
```

Hi! I am having a problem with my boolean code. Every time I try to run this, I keep getting the error:

*NameError: name 'status' is not defined*

How do I define this? I am struggling with functions also, despite them being easy to most people.

Comment: Well, you access a variable `status` in `main()`, the first function you call. But status at that point is not yet defined, in other words, it is an unknown variable you are trying to print. It will be defined in the other functions, but those functions are not called anywhere. You can define status by calling one of your other functions: `status = is_negative(-10)` for example. And then call `main(status)` to print it.

Comment: Or in `main()` you can replace `print(status)` by for example `print(is_negative(-10))`

Comment: so instead of printing status, I should just print the three defs in main such as print(is_negative(number)),  print(is_even(number)) etc?

Comment: Exactly. Each function returns a certain value and when you call the function you get that return value. So in `x = is_negative(-10) ` the value is assigned to x (for later use) and `print(is_negative(-10))` prints the value that is returned. Note that the value is returned, not the name `status`!

Comment: That actually helped a lot, thanks so much!

Comment: Great! See it this way: you give something to a function, the function does something with it and than gives you something in *return*. (Sometimes a function only does something, and returns nothing or `None`. This is the case with your `main()` function. Try, at the bottom of your code: `print(main())` -> what does it return to you?)

Answer (score 0):

You did not define status and you did not call any of your functions to return the values. Here is solution

`def main(): status = is_negative(3) #3 is not negative so function will return False   print(status) #Print the value stored in your variable`